# Nonlinear ODE differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following equation arises when minimizing certain non-equilibrium actions:
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}y=(1+|y|^\alpha)f(t)$$
where $\alpha > 0$ and $f(t)$ is non-negative, smooth, and bounded. I am interested in closed form solutions, i.e. series. I presume equations of this type have been studies before. Where would be a good place to start looking for information?

Since I am interested in large $y$ regimes, I suspect a more tractable equation is
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}y=y^\alpha f(t)$$
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1. They are ODE's, right? There's no need to use the $\partial$ derivative, I guess. 2. An exhaustive source is the
Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations  by Valentin F. Zaitsev and Andrei D. Polyanin (I think you might find it freely online, just google it) 3. If you don't specify $f(t)$, I am skeptical that you will find any explicit result